# When I am passing only www.google.com in the driver.get method, the url is not opening. I am getting a Webdriver Exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Why do we need to pass the complete url in the get method?
e.g if you look the code below:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

The above code works fine but not if we use the below line:

```
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

Why do we need to pass https:// also?

Please help.

Comment: Because `www.google.com` is not a URL. Your web browser converts it to one when you do that yourself, but at the code level, more precision is required.

Comment: The protocol has to be specified and won't be guessed

Answer (score 1):

> The first part of the URL is called a protocol identifier and it indicates what protocol to use, and the second part is called a resource name and it specifies the IP address or the domain name where the resource is located.

So the protocol must be specified. Today some browsers add the protocol for you so you can just type `google.com`

`www.google.com` is only the domain name, which DNS will translate into the ip address of where `www.google.com` is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

HI first we have to understand architecture of the selenium ,

1.Internally selenium works on the concept of [Json wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)

2.This wire protocol defines a RESTful web service using JSON over HTTP.hence protocol is mandatory.

3.Also when you type say www.google.co.in in browser then browser automatically adds http:// before www,to verify the same plz do one thing simply copy and paste any url form the browser in a notepad you will see that protocol in the start of the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium states it is best to use a fully qualified URL.

A fully qualified URL contains the http:// (or https://www ).

SeleniumHQ method detail for get:

> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP GET operation, and the method will block until the load is complete. This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout is over, since should the underlying page change whilst your test is executing the results of future calls against this interface will be against the freshly loaded page. Synonym for WebDriver.Navigation.to(String).
>
> Parameters:
>   url - The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL

www.google.com is not a fully qualified URL.